# What's wrong with my calculator android application?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am making an app that work like calculator..

Here is my code snippet.

```
EditText etfirst,etsecond;
Button btnadd;

etfirst = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etfirst);
etsecond = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etsecond);
btnadd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnadd);

btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int first,second,result;
            first= Integer.valueOf(etfirst.getText().toString());

            second = Integer.valueOf(etsecond.getText().toString());
            result = first + second;
            tvresult.setText("Result: " + result); }
});
```

My problem is that when i get integer value from EditText into TextView it is not working ..

I also tried Integer.parseInt(String a); but it is also not helpful..

Please guide me how to make my code properly

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.ajdeveloper.myapplication, PID: 32227
                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at com.example.ajdeveloper.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)

Comment: 40 line is : second = Integer.valueOf(etsecond.getText().toString());

Comment: Are you putting the code shown in `onCreate`?

Comment: Error message says that `tvresult` variable is null. Did you initialize it?

Comment: Thanxx Guyzz... I was forget to initialize tvresult...  Thanx for positive Reply . I appreciate it..

Answer (score 0):

use property  `inputType:number` or also can `numberDecimal` value of `inputType`.

because by default edittext will accept all character/number etc. but typecast to integer only will work on numeric value.

Comment: Thanx for Reply Bro.. I appreciate it .. but it also not work

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
tvresult.setText("Result: " + result);
```

as

```
tvresult.setText("Result: " + String.valueOf(result));
```

and in the exception it is saying `NullPointerException` bind the variable `tvresult` with your xml object.

Comment: not worked ... Error remain same at 40 line ..   40 line : second = Integer.valueOf(etsecond.getText().toString());

Comment: could you try with `Integer.parseInt(etsecond.getText().toString())` the line 40

Comment: And check your xml file `etsecond` is not binding I guess. Therefore, it is throwing `NullPointerException`